# How to load a view inside layout page by calling controller action in dot net core?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to load a view inside layout page by calling controller action. In asp.net mvc we were doing it by using html helper **@Html.Action** but this helper is not available in dot net core. So how can we do this in dot net core?

Answer (score 1):

Please look at View components in asp.net core mvc it essentially does the job of @html.action of rendering partial views.Below link should be useful:-
[1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax to call controller,and then add the partial view to where you want.
Here is a demo worked:

Controller:

```
public PartialViewResult GetPartialView(int itemSequenceNumber)
        {
            return PartialView("Partials/DemoPartialView", new DemoViewModel { SequenceNumber = itemSequenceNumber });

        }
```

DemoPartialView:

```
@model case1_5_26_.Models.DemoViewModel
@{
}
    <div id="row-item-@Model.SequenceNumber">
        <div></div>
        <button>@Model.SequenceNumber</button>
        <p></p>
    </div>
```

view：

```
<div id="items">

</div>
@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            getPartial(1);
            getPartial(2);
            getPartial(3);
        })
        function getPartial(itemNumber) {
            $.ajax({

                url: '/Test/GetPartialView?itemSequenceNumber=' + itemNumber,
                //type: 'get'
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (newItem) {
                    $(newItem).appendTo($('#items'))
                }
            })
            
        }
    </script>
}
```

result：
[image]